Document Library not redirecting to default.aspx
I have experience with many SharePoints where we turn on Modern Script Editor and allow for custom pages. So when we create a document library and create a default.aspx page in its root folder, a user going to the document library is redirected to default.aspx instead of the normal /forms/allitems.aspx.
I created a new SharePoint and document library like this yesterday, but now the user is not redirected to the default.aspx page but only sees the usual /forms/allitems.aspx.
I created a subfolder with a default.aspx and when visiting the subfolder am redirected to default.aspx like I want to happen in the root folder of the document library.
How can I ensure that the document library root folder redirects to default.aspx?
